# How can I pass request parameters along with pay key in pay pal adaptive embedded payments?

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using light browser embedded into my application. I have form which has the action set to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay".

I have java script that triggers the pay pal pay now button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var embeddedPPFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({trigger: 'submitBtn'});
</script>
```

Now inside my form I have this pay now button and also input parameters set as shown below. I have input parameters as "expType", "payKey" and "custom".

```
<input type="image" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif">
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
<input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value='<%=request.getAttribute("payKey")%>'>
<input id="custom" type="hidden" name="custom" value='<%=(String)request.getAttribute("custom")%>'>
```

But once after the payment occurs and when I get back the asynchronous request to the IPN Notification URL regarding the confirmation of the payment, I am seeing null for "custom" which I have passed one of the input parameters. Can any one please advice is there any way around in passing additional request parameter in adaptive(chained payment) embedded payment?

Answer (score 0):

Well, definitely there is no way directly we can pass any additional input parameter other than pay key in adaptive payment. That's what I have found. So the work around it would be using PayRequest object and set parameter to its TrackingId.

PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest();
  payRequest.setTrackingId("Set Parameter into this");

Use this TrackingId to retrieve in IPN.